# C++: -> operator overloading: Handle const / nonconst access differently

Tags: c++

I'm building a reference counting system and have defined a prototype template class which represents all references to objects that will be used.

The point where I am stuck is that I have to differentiate between const and non const access to those objects through a reference. If the access is const (read-only, or called method of underlying object is flagged const), everything is okay - however if it's not - a copy of the object might have to be created first.

A simplified version of my reference class:

```
template< class T >
class CRef
{
protected:
    T* ptr;

public:

    T* const* operator ->() const { return ptr; };
    T* operator        ->()       { printf( "Non-const access!" ); return ptr; };

};
```

The problem is, that only the non-const -> operator overload function gets called, even when accessing const functions of the underlying object type.

- How do I get the constant dereferencing overloading function to get called properly?

Answer (score 2):

`const` / non-const cannot, in principle, be used to differentiate between read and write access.

You’re out of luck here. The only way to accomplish this is via a proxy object that is returned by `operator ->` and that handles reading via an implicit conversion:

The returned proxy defines an `operator T` (implicit conversion) that is invoked when it is assigned to another object, and an `operator =(T const&)` when something is assigned to it.

```
template <typename T>
class CRef {
    …
    CRefElementProxy<T> operator ->() const { return CRefElementProxy<T>(this); };

    friend CRefElementProxy;
};

template <typename T>
class CRefElementProxy {
    operator T const*() const { return parent->ptr; }
    CRefElementProxy operator =(T const* value) {
        printf("Non-const access!");
        return parent->ptr;
    }
};
```

That’s just a pseudo-codey draft. The real version looks a bit more complex.

Answer (score 2):

The const one is called on const objects.  If you want the const -> called, cast the object reference you have to a const or provide a way to get a const version of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Once the pointer has been returned then there is no way to know what is done with it.